# Filling an array with random elements and using SelectionSort but getting weird error: Fix?

Tags: java, selection-sort

```
class SelectionSort {
public static int[] sort(int[] arr, int n) {
  //int min;
  int temp;
    for(int i=1; i < n; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j <= n; j++)
            if (arr[j] < arr[min])
                min = j;

        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[min];
        arr[min] = temp;
    }
  return arr;
```

}

```
public static int[] fillArray(int[] arr) {
  for (int k=0; k < arr.length; k++) {
     arr[k] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
     System.out.println(arr[k] + " "); 
  }
  return arr;
```

}

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  /* SelectionSort ob = new SelectionSort();
  int n = 100;
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  ob.sort(arr);
  ob.fillArray(arr); */
  int[] arr1 = fillArray(arr1);
  int[] arr2 = sort(arr1);
  for (int i:arr2) {
     System.out.print(i); 
  }
```

}
}

I am getting an odd error saying 'SelectionSort.java:31: error: method sort in class SelectionSort cannot be applied to given types;', any ideas how to fix this? i'm lost.

Comment: Note how many arguments you're giving the sort method, and how many it takes.

Comment: I removed the int n argument, it still is giving errors.

Comment: The `n` parameter is needed for the method to work. You need to give an `n` argument when calling the method. instead The first argument should be the array, then `n`, which appears to be the length of the array.

Comment: One comment said to remove the n argument, one said not to. Even if I removed it I'd still be confused can somebody genuinely help?

Comment: There is no comment saying that you should remove the n argument... Carcigenicate is genuinely helping. His/Her suggestion was to use an extra argument in your method call, which is the length of the array...

Comment: @koder42 No one ever said to remove the `n` parameter. My first comment was trying to get you to think through the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner for loop you have put "j <= n"

for (int j = i+1; j <= n; j++){

So j become size of the array, but max index should  be 1 less than n.